# Exportar dados de banco MySQL para o Excel

Tags: php, mysql, microsoft-excel

Estou executando um post que enviar uma string com todos os títulos e campos de um banco de dados, porém ele só exporta quando envio até 4 meses. Gostaria de poder enviar até 1 ano, como poderia melhorar o código abaixo para criar esse arquivo?

```
    $filename = $_POST['filename'].".xls";
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $filename);
    print_r($_POST['body']);
```

Este é o método que exporta:

```
 public function exportGlobal($post)
    {
        $query = null;

        $startDate = $post['dataInicial'];
        $endDate = $post['dataFinal'];

        $sql = "SELECT
                  `distribuidor`.`dst_nome`,
                  `filial`.`fll_nome`,
                  `usuario`.`usr_nome`, 
                  `venda`.`vnd_valor`,
            FROM
                  `venda`
            LEFT JOIN `usuario`      ON (`venda`.`usr_id` = `usuario`.`usr_id`)
            LEFT JOIN `cliente`      ON (`venda`.`clt_id` = `cliente`.`clt_id`)
            LEFT JOIN `distribuidor` ON (`distribuidor`.`dst_id` = `venda`.`dst_id`)
            LEFT JOIN `filial`       ON (`distribuidor`.`dst_id` = `filial`.`dst_id`)
                WHERE venda.vnd_data
                BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
                  ;";

        $query = $this->executeQuery($sql);
        if ($query != null) {

            $exportBody = array();
            $titulos = array(
                "Distribuidor",
                "Filial do Distribuidor",
                "Vendedor",
                "Valor"
            );
    $exportBody[] = implode("\t", $titulos);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($query); $i++) {
                $data = array(
                    $query[$i]['dst_nome'],
                    $query[$i]['fll_nome'],
                    $query[$i]['usr_nome'],
                    $query[$i]['vnd_valor'],
                );

                $data = removeTagsSaltosDeLinha($data);

                $exportBody[] = implode("\t", $data);
     }
     $exportBody = implode("\n", $exportBody);
     return str_replace('"', "", $exportBody);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não acha melhor usar uma classe própria para isso?
Eu recomendo a classe [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), que é fácil de trabalhar e bem completa. Nela consigo exportar milhares de registros sem complicações.